# ASP.NET: Is there an easy way to include one instance of a div in several master pages?

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I have 3 master pages, one for the home page, one for a two column layout and one for a three column layout.

They are all working fine, but there are a number of divs that are shared across the two of, or all of the pages.  A couple of them are quite complex so ideally I'd just like to be able to have them coded once, and then shared across the master pages.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Many thanks in advance,
Ross

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this method of including the same code snippets in my multiple master pages:

```
    <!-- #include virtual = "/shared/divCookies.inc" -->
```

Answer (score 4):

[Nested Master Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2b3ktt7.aspx) may be the solution to your problem, depending on your exact structure. In essence you can give a master page to your master page so you have one site master page which has your site banner, etc. (and I'm hoping your div is along these lines) and then three master pages for home, two col and three col that refer to the site master page as their master.

Whether this works does depend on exactly how your pages are structured and whether that div is similarly placed on all pages, etc.

Otherwise your option is as Johann said to use a UserControl that you can include on each of your current master pages. This might not be a bad idea if it is a self contained thing even if you do the Nested Master Page method.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use User Controls ([MSDN Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wb1a0e.aspx)) and include them in the Master Pages? This gives a you a single control and code base for all those shared resources.